# Store a function that returns an array into a two dimensional array

Tags: java

I'm trying to store a byte buffer into a two dimensional array.

```
byte[][] input = new byte[128][];
int index = 3;

ByteBuffer b = new ByteBuffer.allocate(128); 
b.limit(128);

b.put....

input[index][] = b.get();
```

I get an illegal start of expression error at the second [ ].

Comment: What's an "illegal start error"?

Comment: illegal start of expression - sorry, I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be `input[index] = b.get();`.

Comment: Maybe you should just delete this wreck of a question. It's not like it'll be of help to others.